# getSherlockActivity() vs getActivity()

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using SherlockFragment and until today I've always used the getActivity() method to get an instance of the activity hosting the fragment. Now I realiced there's also this method in the SherlockFragment API.. which one should I use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like `getSherlockActivity` is just a shortcut to:

```
(SherlockActivity) getActivity()
```