# To use getSherlockActivity() or getActivity() or other?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an Android app with TabManager. Due to change of Android API, I need to upgrade my app for Activity to contain the Fragment. To provide backward compatibility, I use ActionBarSherlock.

My App is working fine. However, looking at the Google Play Developer Console, there is always few crash reports on "java.lang.NullPointerException" on the line with getSherlockActivity(), I think only less than 0.1% out of total users are affected.

For example,

```
// Example 1    
File file = new File(getSherlockActivity().getCacheDir(), "filename");
// Example 2
getSherlockActivity().setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

My question:
1. Should I change all the getSherlockActivity() to getActivity()? Or under certain rule, it is mandatory to use one of them?
2. What is the difference between them?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The low error rate says to me that this may be a symptom of your activity being destroyed (whilst suspended) by the OS due to resource constraints and then re-created when the user returns to it but not properly restored (usually because activity state isn't being saved correctly). You can test this by turning on developer option "Don't keep activities", and then switching between your activity and another app, and then back again. I find it helpful to do most of my dev/test work with this turned on, it flushes out corner cases that you'd otherwise not notice until the crash reports arrive.

Comment: Thanks all. Managed to rectify the problem which is due to onPostExecute of AsyncTask after the Activity is destroyed (pressing back button). But I wonder why the Fragment process can still run as its Activity is already been destroyed ?

Comment: That'll be because the AsyncTask is just that - asynchronous - and has lived beyond the Activity (or Fragment) that started it. To quote from developer.android.com - "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations". If the task hasn't finished before the activity gets destroyed, I'd say its too long. The AsyncTask JavaDoc suggests alternative approaches for long-running background tasks. Essentially, AsyncTask is there to take 'real work' off the UI thread and stop the UI feeling laggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that with `getSherlockActivity ()` you get the result of `getActivity()` but casted as a SherlockActivity. This allows to get access to the ABS specific apis.

If you just need something that is general enough to be in the `Activity` class, just use `getActivity()`. It will highlight this, otherwise highlight the fact that you use something that is ABS specific using `getSherlockActivity ()`.

The NPE can come from :

- using `getActivity()` (or siblings...) before onAttach has been executed
- using `getActivity()` (or siblings...) after onDetach has been executed

So the solution is to check if your fragment is attached before using its activity :

```
if( isAttached() ) {
   getActivity()....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138969/getsherlockactivity-vs-getactivity)

The NullPointerException is [normally](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

> Caution: If you need a Context object within your Fragment, you can call getActivity(). However, be careful to call getActivity() only when the fragment is attached to an activity. When the fragment is not yet attached, or was detached during the end of its lifecycle, getActivity() will return null.

Answer (score 1):

This exception probably means that the code is being exectuted when the fragment is not attached to an activity.

The reference returned by getSherlockActivity() is set when the Fragment is attached, and then cleared (set to null) when the Fragment is detached. If your code tries to reference getSherlockActivity() before or after this, you would get a null-pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`getSherlockActivity` is just a shortcut to:

```
(SherlockActivity) getActivity()
```

So in your case there is no problem to use  `getActivity()` instead in Example 1  but in Example 2 it will not work since it is a method of SherlockActivity.